# 12V DC Overvoltage Protection

Tags: switches, battery-charging, dc-motor, 12v, electric-machine

I'm trying to create a air pump system with a rechargeable battery pack. My question is:

- Because my air pump is a positive desplacement pump, which task is to create a vacuum in a container, will its voltage increase above 12V when the workload increase (because vacuum) and will I need a overvoltage protection system for the DC motor?
- If so, is it possible to get a overvoltage system that will cut off the current to the momentary ON/OFF switch?

I would also appreciate any comments on the schematics below.

Thanks for any help!

[image: Circuitsystem]

Comment: The motor voltage will not increase above the specified voltage, but the speed and current taken will vary with load.

Comment: power supply looks a bit dodgy.  you probaby want a bit more than 12V into the BMS , and is a phone charger strong enough to provide the power levels needed?

Comment: I took the BMS setup from a youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuEgZELszLk)(2:10 into the video). I updated the schematics (https://imgur.com/a/Jnvp0) now, and removed the USB charging with a standard 230v to 12v adapter. But is the flyback diode and capacitor placed right? And which voltage size do they need to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a brushed motor -

You likely don't need an 'overvoltage' protection, but you probably do need some sort of flyback diode and a small capacitor across your motor terminals.

When your momentary switch to your motor opens up, you will likely get an inductive kick-back which needs to go somewhere.  The diode provides that path.

One final note, in most air systems that are radial in nature (your computer fan is axial), if there is a vacuum, the load actually decreases.

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-Electric-12V-Micro-Vacuum-Air-Pump-Booster-For-Medical-Treatment-Instrument/282489988597?epid=905903363&hash=item41c5b725f5:g:kJoAAOSw-3FZH9~z

Comment: This is the DC motor and pump. Will the load decrease when it becomes harder and harder to suck air out of the container?

Comment: Yes, the load will decrease.  Think of it in terms of torque, as there is less air in the tank, the torque required to turn the motor actually decreases.  Torque would be 0 in space!  Current is nearly proportional with torque in a DC motor, thus current decreases as the torque is removed.  This is why your vacuum cleaner increases speed when you plug the inlet!

Comment: I updated the schematics (imgur.com/a/Jnvp0) now, and removed the USB charging with a standard 230v to 12v adapter. But is the flyback diode and capacitor placed right? And which voltage size do they need to be?

Comment: The capacitor is s placed correctly.  The diode is not, it should be placed across the motor terminals as well.  It should be pointing 'up'.  [Check this out](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/r/400-400/assets/9/8/6/0/f/51770c5bce395f3149000000.png)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will keep updating this thread as I go along creating it!